# How to dig from root to bottom?

Tags: dns, dig

I'm trying to fetch DNS data without any local or ISP resolvers using the `DIG` tool.

For example I try `google.nl`

I start at a rootserver (d.root-servers.net):

`dig @199.7.91.13 google.nl`

Then I take the registry from this:

`;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.dns.nl.             172800  IN      A       193.176.144.5`

`dig @193.176.144.5 google.nl`

`;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.nl.              3600    IN      NS      ns2.google.com.`

Now here is where I get stuck. Because google.nl uses the nameservers of `google.com`, it won't send any glue records.

Should I then dig from root again for `google.com`?

`dig @199.7.91.13 google.com`

`;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.5.6.30`

`dig @192.5.6.30 google.com`

Now in this case, google.com is using it's own nameservers so glue records are provided in the `;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:`, but it is possible this domain would be using different nameservers.

Then you'd need to fetch those nameservers, I feel like you could go on like that in an endless way untill you are being served an actual IP address instead of a reference to a nameserver.

Is that how it works, or is there a shorter way to the IP address of a nameserver (so to get the IP address of `ns2.google.com` from `google.nl`?

Comment: It's simpler, yet more complicated than that.  The hierarchy is actually meant to be preserved and you should not bypass it by polling higher level DNS servers unless you have to.

Comment: Remember that your resolver may have cached information already, so it might already know the A records for ns2.google.com (for example).

Comment: I'm building a little tool to check domain configuration, so I need the most current information. Now in this case another hierarchical query for the nameservers may be needed, as it can be possible to work on multiple domains. I think a list of the TLD nameservers could be locally cached, that would at least save the root queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way it works. Not ideal, to be sure. Resolvers will hit hardcoded limit if recursion goes for too long... See for example 
https://cybermashup.com/2014/09/23/how-dns-kills-the-internet/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ host -t ns google.nl|cut -d" " -f4|xargs -l1 host
ns2.google.com has address 216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com has address 216.239.32.10
ns4.google.com has address 216.239.38.10
ns3.google.com has address 216.239.36.10
```

Comment: This uses the local resolver or configured resolver, I want to get the IP-address from the hierarchy top to bottom.